# Can't run Fuchsia components with shell

Tags: fuchsia

So I am trying to get started developing on Fuchsia and I wanted to get the hello world component to run. However, following these [steps](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/run/run-examples#include-the-example-package-in-your-fuchsia-image) doesn't work for me. I'm using core.qemu-x64 running on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM with Virtual Box. I have gotten the emulator to run with `fx qemu -N` but `fx vdl start -N` hasn't worked for me.

I run `fx serve-updates` but it just outputs "Discovery..." and never changes. Then I try to run `fx shell run fuchsia-pkg://fuchsia.com/hello-world-cpp#meta/hello-world-cpp.cmx` but it says "No devices found." It seem like this shouldn't be an issue because with Linux the device finder should automatically pick it up. Regardless I tried following the MAC instructions and setting the device with `fx set-device 127.0.0.1:22`. That just makes the run command say "ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused". I also tried to set it to the device to the nodename outputted by the `fx qemu -N command` which is "fuchsia-####-####-####" but that just makes the run command say no devices are found again.

I have verified that I actually have the hello-world packages with the `fx list-packages hello-world` which outputs all the hello-world packages as expected.

Is there any way I can get the device to be discoverable by the shell command? Alternatively, can I run components like the hello-world component from the qemu emulator directly?

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just wasn't patient enough. I assumed the emulator was done getting setup because it stopped giving console output and it allowed me to input commands but it seems I just had to wait longer. After 50 minutes of the `fx qemu -N` command running, the terminal that had `fx serve-updates` going finally picked up the device. Then I was able to execute the hello world component. It would be nice if the documentation at least gave an idea of how long the different commands would take before they'd be usable.

Comment: Does your computer support kvm? If so, consider using that to improve the emulator speed.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I don't believe so, I tried before to make it work but I couldn't figure it out. It isn't a huge deal since I can still make changes without having to re-run everything.